# How to convert C# object property values to N decimal array

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I want to convert my object property values to array like this. (This list comes from database as object dynamically.)

```
  var myobject = List<object> {
    new { name="john", age=25 },
    new { name="bill", age=26 },
    new { name="scott", age=27 }
  }
```

When I send this object to user via asp.net web api, it return like this:

```
  [
    { name:"john", age:25 },
    { name:"bill", age:26 },
    { name:"scott", age:27 }
  ]
```

But I want to send my response as array like this:

```
  [
    ["john",  25 ],
    [ "bill", 26 ],
    [ "scott", 27 ]
  ]
```

My object properties may be change by request.

I need to create an N decimal array for my object proerty values. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are they really `object` here? Don't you have the initial data in an actual class?

Comment: They are object yes, not a standart calss.

Comment: If the properties are dynamic, then you're going to have to resort to reflection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use reflection if you don't know the names of the properties. For example:

```
var results = myobject.Select(o => 
    o.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(o)));
```

However, as a point to note, because you are not sending the name of the property along with the value, that would lead to some ambiguity. For example, if the object looked like this `{ age = 15, shoeSize = 10 }`, you would be sending out `[11, 10 ]`. So the consuming service would need to explicitly know what was being sent back.

Edit: Here's a fiddle showing how it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iej1pO

Comment: Yes I do not know propert names. is myobject my List<> ?

Comment: So give this a try then, it gives exactly the output you asked for.

Comment: On what? My code won't do that, but whatever you are passing it or is receiving it might.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.